# Firemonkey component move at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Intro:

I have a custom VCL component derived from the TCustomPanel class which purpose is to act as some kind of a custom form which has a parent (main form), but all default buttons such as maximize, minimize, close. That component was developed long before FMX and it's an important part of an existing application. The component is catching messages, overriding the Paint method etc.

The main feature of this component is to have similar functionality as a regular form (floating at runtime within it's parent, dragging ...) but with some customized graphics (smaller buttons etc...)

[image: Demo application]

Task at hand:

I am working on rewriting components for FireMonkey (Delphi XE2) including this floating window as well and if there is any point to do that.
 
(I don't want to mix VCL and FMX because at some point I would like to have whole application in FMX.)

Questions:

1. Is there any existing FMX control with feature of floating /
   dragging / moving in runtime?
2. What is the approach in Firemonkey to enable for an eg. TPanel move
   in run time or is there a control which offers that functionality by
   default? I guess the whole idea in FMX is to override existing
   methods.
3. Is it possible in same application to have forms with different
   styles? I am thinking about creating my custom form with custom
   style. In that case I can have one main form (parent) and child
   forms which have different style.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't ask "Do you think..." - you'll get downvoted or get close votes. Instead, ask for specific advice: "How can I..." and if you're concerned about opinions, ask for other approaches you may have missed. I'd suggest improving the formatting, too - eg, make a dot point list of up to three short, one-sentence questions. This is how to get past the SO gremlins and keep what is an interesting question alive :)

Comment: Word of advice, if you're looking to port something to FMX then you shouldn't port it Firemonkey XE2(1.0), FMX was in something like an alpha stage back then and Soo much has changed in XE3&XE4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 and 2, you'll find the OnMouseXXXX events easy enough to use yourself (or the protected virtual methods if you're developing a custom component).

For 3, place a TStyleBook on each form and load the desired style into it (remembering to set the StyleBook property of the form). You can also point the StyleBook property to an instance not on the form, e.g. on another form or to a global object. If you do this beware to nil the StyleBook property of the form before freeing it or you'll get AVs.

Comment: I guess I can use only OnMouseXXX events for moving object while mouse cursor usually stays within a control. For a sizing control (where mouse cursor can be outside a control) I guess I have to override its parent's OnMouseXXX event and do some coding there? About style book... If I do so in Delphi XE2 only form contents are styled but not form controls such as form buttons (maximize, minimize, close...), frame, non client area. How to change that?

Comment: Non-client area styling is only available from XE3 onwards.

Comment: Here is the working example: https://engineertips.wordpress.com/2019/05/06/firemonkey-move-component-at-runtime/